# Show ENOENT Error while authorizing an org

Tags: salesforce, authorize

I have tired to authorize an salesforce org, but i am getting ENOENT error. I tried many times, its not working. I have re-installed VS code and  java 11 JDK, and tired but it is not authorizing any org. I have gone throught some blogs and tired to resolve that error but i failed. Kindly help with this issue.
Error :
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
at onErrorNT
at process._tickCallback

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue before and the best solution I got was to run the sfdx command or use the command palette from a sfdx project folder (i.e. the one that consists sfdx-project.json).

Follow the simple steps given below.

1. navigate to your sfdx project folder in explorer.
2. open the folder with VS Code.
3. wait for VS code to determine its a sfdx project folder so that `SFDX: Authorize an Org` appears in the command palette or run
   `sfdx force:auth:web:login -u alias` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

For authorizing the org, try the below command sfdx force:auth:device:login It will give you the code and URL.put the URL in the browser and enter the code.It will ask for credentials. Enter your credentials and complete the process.If this information helps, please mark the answer as best. Thank you